# Use a different legend to dimension on VizFrame Chart

Tags: sapui5

I would like to show a concatenation fields as axis labels on a chart, is this possible?

So, for the given data:

```
{d: [ {
      "Category": "Vendor",
      "BusinessProcess": "Create Manufacture's Part",
      "Scenario": "Create Vendor - General Data",
      "Role": "General",
      "Average_Duration_Days": 43,
      "Row_ID": "4"
    },
    {
      "Category": "Vendor",
      "BusinessProcess": "Create Vendor - General Data",
      "Scenario": "Create Vendor - General Data",
      "Role": "General",
      "Average_Duration_Days": 38,
      "Row_ID": "5"
    }
```

I would like to use `Average_Duration_Days` as the measure. I would also like to show both rows and the for the label for the row show something like `BusinessProcess + Role`.

Is it possible to use Row_ID as the dimension and then a concatenation of the other fields as the axis label?

Here's a simple code bin:

http://jsbin.com/yifejik/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute 'value' as the selector for your Bars and 'displayValue' as the label. I used a formatter to combine two values.

See jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/wumozevimi/edit?js,output

You could also add a second dimension and include it into your categoryAxis-Feed.